# Compile and Install qtjackctl on Mac OS X

Tags: installation, compile, qt, jackd

Is it possible to compile and install qjackctl on Mac OS X?  If so how do you?

EDIT: When I try to install it it does this: http://paste.pocoo.org/raw/G9610d6NviAZQ7nnZCwQ/
any ideas as to why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. You can install Qt and Jack separately, but I wouldn't recommend that since they will probably have dependencies that you'd be missing. Instead, you can install Macports (http://www.macports.org) and then install QjackCtl from there. Pretty easy.